# "Ask on which site" list does not include sites I've added to "Your Sites" list

Tags: support, android-app

I added about 10 sites to "Your Sites" list of the app. However, when asking a question, the "Ask on which site" box only offers three sites to choose from.

Why is this happening?

Comment: OK. What exactly is the question?

Comment: You have accounts on two sites (and possibly also a meta site for SO), so that's probably the three right there.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realize this was for questions too. Thought it was just for feedback/bug reporting. The reason I thought it showed up wrong is that I don't remember ever signing up for one of the three that did show up so I thought it was just randomly popping up. I thought it was supposed to show a list of all sites so you could choose from all of them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two separate lists.

The "Your Sites" list is kind of "site bookmark", you can put any site there and visit it quickly, whether you have account there or not.

The "Ask on which site" list will show only sites you have joined, either from the app or from the website itself.

Adding a site to "Your Sites" list does not make you join it. To join a site through the app you need to perform an actual action on the site (e.g. upvote, downvote, post comment) then you are given such a dialog:

> [image]

And confirming this will make you join the site.

Comment: The fact that the join-this-site dialog is titled "Add to *your sites*?" makes this kind of super confusing. Alas, AFAIK the apps are not currently being actively developed, so I doubt this will get fixed any time soon.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen well joining new site indeed add it to the list as far as I remember (up to 5 sites) so the message is not wrong.